# Guide on How to Load CSS File Per Role

Tags: 7, theming, users

I'm looking for the simplest solution to allow a custom CSS page to load per role. I have to the CSS pages done, but just need to load them and ensure they are only loaded based on user role.

I'm guessing it should be about three lines of PHP to go at the bottom of the template.php, but not sure what the code should be. Any advice?

Thanks.

---

With relation to the answer and my comment below, tried the beneath code unsuccessfully using the [bamboo theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bamboo)

```
function bamboo_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;

  if (in_array('testtest', $user->roles)) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bamboo') . '/roleedits.css');
  }
}
```

If my code wrong or is it a problem with the theme?

(for the record I did create a role called testtest.)

The error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare bamboo_preprocess_page() (previously declared in E:\Test\sites\all\themes\bamboo\template.php:231) in E:\Test\sites\all\themes\bamboo\template.php on line 385
```

---

NOTE: Both the solution below work. I just accepted the one I used. However both have been tested and work fine, just the second solution offered me more flexibility to call roles again in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User slivorezka posted the answer before me, and I'm just adding some of my own amendments.

**1. Body classes**

First, I think using separate files for this is wrongg. Drupal core comes with a nice feature that it adds "logged-in" class to the body tag if the user is logged in. Similarly, you could use a preprocess function to add a class to the body tag, which lists user role IDs. Then, merge and optimize your CSS to use this class to change the appearance.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($GLOBALS['user']->roles)) {
    foreach ($GLOBALS['user']->roles as $rid => $role_name) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier("drupal-role-$rid-$role_name");
    }
  }
}
```

Copy the above snippet to your theme or to a custom module, and change "`THEMENAME`" to the name of module/theme.

You will see class names like `drupal-role-2-authenticated-user` in the body tag, which you can use to change appearance.

**2.  hook_page_alter() or hook_preprocess_page() (there are other hooks too)**

See the [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/121473/1899) answer.

Comment: After trying 1 above, this works fine. If you are used to using Chrome Developer Tools/some other equivalent this works really well. Also allows me to pull selections again in the future and means I can keep all my CSS adjustments in CSS Injector (https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) files.

Answer (score 4):

Add the next code to you **template.php**

```
/**
 * Implement hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;

  if (in_array('DESIRED_ROLE', $user->roles)) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . '/YOUR_CSS_NAME.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but I had problems with it. I have updated my question with the error message and current code I have as it doesn't format well in a comment. Is my code wrong, or is it a problem with the theme? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: So, you have duplicate "bamboo_preprocess_page()" function. You need delete one function. See line 385 in the your "template.php". But if the first  "bamboo_preprocess_page()" function include some other functionality (some code) - you need add to it the next code:
`global $user;

  if (in_array('DESIRED_ROLE', $user->roles)) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . '/YOUR_CSS_NAME.css');
  }`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The other preprocess_page() function was already being called by the theme itself by default, so it is sort of a problem with the theme.